# DCEVM java patch is not working

Tags: java

I am trying to replace standard JVM of **jdk1.8.0_112** with **Dynamic Code Evolution VM** using

**DCEVM-light-8u112-installer.jar**

but when i checked jvm version after patching with command

**c:>java -version**

it is still showing same Server VM as below

**1 java version "1.8.0_112"**

**2 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)**

**3 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)**

at line number 3, i am expecting type of Server VM as

**Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b01-dcevmlight-10, mixed mode)**

please guide me on this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The light version of the DCEVM project provides a single `jvm.dll` file that is a replacement for the default `jvm.dll` file included with Oracle/OpenJDK JDKs. The light version does not overwrite the file included with the JDK/JRE installation but rather installs the DCEVM JVM as an alternate implementation. Therefore, `java -version` will continue to show the default Java version details.

If DCEVM was installed successfully, `java -version -XXaltjvm=dcevm` will show the DCEVM version details, as expected.

`java -version` will return the DCEVM JVM version details if the full version of DCEVM is installed. Currently the DCEVM project provides full binaries only for Java 7. However, there is very little functional difference between the light and full versions so there is no real need to install the full version.